# How do I create my own wildcard certificate on Linux?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

Does anyone know if it's possible to create my own wildcard certificate under Ubuntu?  For instance, I want the following domains to use one certificate:

```
https://a.example.com
https://b.example.com
https://c.example.com
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just follow [one](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3) of the [many](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html) [step](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/618) by step instructions for creating your own certificate with OpenSSL but replace the "Common Name" `www.example.com` with `*.example.com`.

Usually you have to keep a bit more money ready to get a certificate for this.

```
> openssl req -new -x509 -keyout cert.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:DE
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Germany
Locality Name (eg, city) []:nameOfYourCity
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:nameOfYourCompany
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:nameOfYourDivision
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:*.example.com
Email Address []:webmaster@example.com
```

*(Sorry, my favorite howto is a german text that I don't have readily available and can't find currently, thus the 'many' links)*

Edit in 2017: The original answer to this question is from 2009, when the choice for certificates did not include fully automated and free options like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Nowadays (if the "domain-validated" certification level of Let's Encrypt *is* enough for your purpose) it's trivial to obtain individual certificates for each and every subdomain. In case you need a higher trust level than domain-validated, wildcard certificates are still an option.

Also from 2017, note the comment below, by @ha9u63ar:

According RFC 2818 sec. 3 using CN for host name identification is not recommended anymore (deprecated) Subject Alternative Name (SAN) seems to be the way to go.

My answer to this comment: I trust that nowadays any CAs that issue Wildcard certs will have a proper set of instructions. For a self-signed quick fix, I'd not worry. On the other hand, with LetsEncrypt being around these days, it's been a long time since I've created a self-signed certificate. Gee, this answer really shows its age.

Comment: Can I run that from any host or just the one from where my sites reside on?

Comment: You can use that on any host. But if the request goes to www.example.net while the certificate is for *.example.com (note the net/com difference) you'll get the usual non-matching-certificate warning. However, you can have a number of different machines, one serving www.example.com, another a.example.com, b.example.com etc. and all machines use the same certificate. It breaks only when you access them with a non-matching domain name.

Comment: I believe this works for `https://xyz.example.com`, but not for `https://example.com`. Google for the SAN (subjectAltName) extension.

Comment: Just to add the German tutorial that @OlafKock mentioned (for people like me), I guess it is [this one here](https://thomas-leister.de/internet/eine-eigene-openssl-ca-erstellen-und-zertifikate-ausstellen/#) which is very complete and understandable (IMHO).

Comment: According RFC 2818 sec. 3 using CN for host name identificate is not recommended anymore (deprecated) Subject Alternative Name (SAN) seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @OlafKock can the CN common name be "any" ? I mean just a wild card , just put "*" 
is it working ?

Comment: @thahgr if you'd find a CA that would do that, they'd be shut down immediately. You can't prove that you have ownership of "*" - as you could for "*.example.com". Also, I'm not sure if that would be recursive for multiple subdomains, or just for one. You might want to try that yourself with a self-signed certificate for "*" that _you_ trust manually, and then run one of your sites as `example` (one level) and `www.example.com` (three levels) using that certificate.

Comment: just for test purposes, i might give it a try , thanks for your answer

Comment: It's a useless experiment though. If you have that kind of control over the browser's trust, you'd rather create your own root CA.